# How to setup a virtual environment for python in Visual Studio Code using the command line

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I am a very new programmer trying to learn Flask now that I've learned the basics of Python. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA&t=355s ... I am stuck at 5:46.

The tutorial, as well as documentation on several other websites, explains to type in the following command:`\env\Scripts\activate.bat` for Windows, and they suggest using:`source env/bin/activate` for Mac.

This is what I get in return:

```
\env\Scripts\activate.bat : The term '\env\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ \env\Scripts\activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\env\Scripts\activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx  
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: The command \env\Scripts\activate.bat was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\\env\Scripts\activate.bat". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
```

Until this point everything else had gone smoothly.This is what I've done leading up to this point:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv env
```

After running these commands, the tutorial asks me to run the command I'm having problems with.

What options do I have to fix this??

Answer (score 2):

You probably have not set the path variable so the system can't find the Scripts folder.  In a typical Python installation on Windows (which you seem to be using), Python is installed under the C drive in Program Files, and inside that directory is the Scripts directory, which is where `virtualenv.exe` lives.

So you need to open Control Panel, go to System, click on Advanced System Settings, click on Environment Variables, then under USER variables highlight Path, click on Edit, and see if the path to Scripts exists; it'll be something like:
`C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts`
If it's not there you need to click New and enter it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `.` before the `\env\...` path. This implies that, instead `\env\Scripts\activate.bat` do **`.\env\Scripts\activate`**. 
Moreover, you can navigate to the `venv\Scripts\` folder and type `activate`.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. I tried it and got a different error in return.  This time the error says "cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system."

Answer (score 0):

copy this term and past your command line in your PyCharm and enter:

```
.\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and solved it like this:

- Search in the Windows search bar "powershell" and run it as Administrator.
- Then run `Get-ExecutionPolicy`.
- After that, run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and enter "y" as an answer to the prompt.
- Then run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`.
- Then run `.\env\Scripts\activate` this command in VSCode or any other editor.

[image: Command line window screenshot]